# Primefaces PickList update target list on transfer

Tags: primefaces, target, transfer

I want to update the lists in the bean when the user transfers an item from one list to another. Is there a way to do that?

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

In the xhtml:

```
<p:pickList value="#{myBean.myDepartment}" onTransfer="handleTransfer(e)"....>
```

In the bean:

```
List<Department> selectedDepartments = new ArrayList<Department>();
List<Department> availableDepartments = getAvailableDepartments();

private DualListModel<Department> myDepartment;
myDepartment = new DualListModel<Department>(availableDepartments, selectedDepartments);
```

On Commit, Departments selected by the user can be accessed using selectedDepartments

And the script ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleTransfer(e) {
    item = e.item;
    alert(item.text());

    fromList = e.from;
    toList = e.to;
    type = e.type; //type of transfer; command, dblclick or dragdrop)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is more complex than that. What I want to do is the next thing. When I click JUST on a target item, display an outputpanel. I have done this but not correctly cuz when I click on a source item, the outputpanel is shown too, so, I need to check in the Bean if the item is on the target or source and I cant do it submitting, I cant put a button to 'confirm' or like that (cant beacause of the requeriments of the project). So I need that the lists in the bean will be updated when I move an item to the target. I dont know if is more clear now...

Comment: I am sorry. Requirement is not clear yet. When an item is moved from source to target, that selected item is automatically pushed to the list selectedDepartments in my example. So selected items are available in the list selectedDepartments for further processing

Comment: Like you said, On Commit, selectedDepartments is available to be accesed, but not when u just drag the item to the targe (no commit process). That's what I want, in the onTransfer event, make like a commit action to update the target list. Is clear now?

Comment: The valueChangeListener of pickList is not invoked unless page submit happens. So, there is no way you track the items being added at server side. Option left out is client side onTransfer. Updated the answer with the same.

Comment: @rags How can we get value of the item?

Comment: @dj aqeel, in the bean, the selectedDepartments list gives the items that are selected

Comment: @rags I was asking, how to do that in javascript? just like we got the text by item.text()

Comment: @dj aqeel, item.text() gives the actual value as it is seen in the selected value list of user interface. item.index() gives the index of the selected item in the selected value list of user interface.

Comment: Now, with PrimeFaces 3.4 (to be released soon - http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2066), ajax event on transfer is provided. With this, we will be able to track the selected values even before submit

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what do you want. This is done automatically same as if you type something into `p:inputText` it is available in beans property representing the value of `p:inputText` without need of manual update.

Just access the updated values in your `pickList` with `getTarget()` or `getSource()` methods. You are probably trying to access `lists` which you provided to `DualListModel` directly like:

```
DualListModel<fooType> fooModel = new DualListModel<fooType>(fooList1,fooList2);
// transfer item
// check if fooList2 is updated - this is wrong, it is **not** updated
fooModel.getTarget(); // this way you can get the actual values of target list
```

`target` - right side, `source` - left side of a `pickList`.