# primefaces how to retrieve changed values from picklist

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

i have implemented the following picklist:

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}" var="cRVariable" itemValue="#{cRVariable}" itemLabel="#{cRVariable.varName}" converter="#{cRImageTypeConverter}" immediate="true" rendered="true" >
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available Variables</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Associated Variables</f:facet>                
</p:pickList>                       
<f:facet name="footer"> 
    <p:commandButton id='varassociate' action="#{reportConfiguratorBean.setAssocImTypVariables()}" value='Associate' process="@this,pickList" />
</f:facet>
```

Picklist is populated correctly (using getAssocImTypVariables() from database). But my **ISSUE** is that **i can not capture the changed picklist values** of a user alters the source and target lists. I am trying to capture the changes using a commandButton method "setAssocImTypVariables" as follows:

```
public void setAssocImTypVariables() {      
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entered");          
    List<CRVariable> sourceVariables = this.dualListVars.getSource();
    List<CRVariable> targetVariables = this.dualListVars.getTarget();       

    System.out.println(dualListVars.getSource());
    System.out.println(dualListVars.getTarget());

    for (CRVariable sourceVariable:sourceVariables) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a source variable: " + sourceVariable.getVarName());
    }       
    for (CRVariable targetVariable:targetVariables) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: " + targetVariable.getVarName());
    }       
    }
```

So if for example i have a picklist with INITIAL source = (Obj1,Obj2,Obj3,Obj5,Obj7) and target = (Obj4,Obj6), i move "Obj1" from source to target BUT in my console i get:

--------- entered
[]
[]

So my dualListVars (source and target) is not populated! I have two empty lists for source and target...

**So my method CAN NOT perceive picklist's changes... Any ideas?
I am new to java + primefaces so it could be something really fundamental :(**

I am also attaching the method  getAssocImTypesOnLoad():

```
public void getAssocImTypesOnLoad() {               
    Long imTypeId = Long.parseLong(virtualId);      
    List<CRVariable> source;
    List<CRVariable> target;        
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;      
    try 
    {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();            
        String hq3 = "select distinct v from CRVariable v join v.crimagetypes t where t.id in (:itid)";
        Query query3 = session.createQuery(hq3);
        query3.setParameter("itid",imTypeId);
        target = query3.list();
        String hq4 = "select v FROM CRVariable v WHERE v.id not in (" +
                "select distinct v1.id " +
                "from CRVariable v1 " +
                "join v1.crimagetypes t2 " +
                "where t2.id in (:itid))";
        Query query4 = session.createQuery(hq4);
        query4.setParameter("itid",imTypeId);
        source = query4.list();
        dualListVars = new DualListModel<CRVariable>(source, target);
        tx.commit();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if (tx != null) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    finally 
    {
       session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: My backbean is SessionScoped ...

Comment: This might be useful ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622582/primefaces-picklist-update-target-list-on-transfer/10630201#10630201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `immediate=true` attribute on the `commandButton`?

If I remember it correctly, according to an article from [balusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)
[check it out here](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#AddImmediateTrueToUICommandOnly) an `immediate=true` on a commandButton should skip the `apply model to values phase`.

Maybe that is the reason, why your model is not updated?

(Just a guess by looking at the code - I have not reproduced this.)

Comment: If i try to remove immediate="true" then if i call "#{reportConfiguratorBean.readMyAssocImTypVariables}" my whole portlet goes down.

Comment: The only things i have in my log are messages like:  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ImageViewer Servlet threw exception
javax.portlet.faces.BridgeException: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /views/report-configurator.xhtml @269,45 value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.getAssocImTypVariables()}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation  ----

Comment: These messages are relevant to picklist value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.getAssocImTypVariables()}" Method which however WORKS!

Comment: I have updated my initial post and added getAssocImTypVariables()

Comment: For the `PropertyNotWritableException`: Do you have an attribute `assocImTypVariables` on your `reportConfiguratorBean`? You do not need to explicitly call the `get` and `set` methods. Just write `value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.assocImTypVariables}"`. 
It is hard to follow everything in your code. You should try to strip the problem down and maybe create a little example just for this one problem. This will help yourself to track it down and also make it easier for everyone here on stackoverflow to follow the problem and help you.

Comment: Changed picklist value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}"
and eliminated p:commandButton immediate="true" .... But eventhough my picklist is loaded with source and target values if i make changes (transfer) and submit, the method setAssocImTypVariables() fails to get Source and Target for global variable dualListVars...

Comment: My recommendation is to strip this down to a working example and change things one by one so you can narrow down the problem. It is hard to oversee your code as you only provided snippets of it and I guess it would become too large when you provide everything. The more you can isolate the problem yourself the higher are the chances that some one here can help.

Comment: Actually the  problem is quite simple. I use a picklist which is populated correctly " value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}"" but when i transfer some items from source to target i can not fetch the updated DualListModel ... My method "setAssocImTypVariables()" can not fetch dualListVars object ... I am trying to strip the problem down, but picklist seem to be a quite complex component with alotof interconnections... Anyhow thanks for instructions!

Comment: You could start with primefaces show case on [picklist] (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf). Just copy the code from the simple example and see if that simple example works in your environment. Then extend it one by one to what you need and see where it breaks.

Comment: It is solved! Your suggestions was useful/correct BUT my Eclipse project needed to be Cleaned in order for the code to work!

Comment: Are you talking about the `immediate=true`? or about something else? Please mark the answer as "useful" then. Or edit the answer and add what ever solved your problem so others may benefit from it in the future.

Comment: Yes i am talking about immediate=true. By mistake i have marked as accepted the wrong answer. I hope now it is ok! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look to the primefaces showcase :  [Primefaces picklist](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf)

Call the `dualListVars` directly. `#{reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}` is resolved to `reportConfiguratorBean.getDualListVars()` since dualListVars is a property (eg. a property with a getter and a setter).

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}" var="cRVariable" itemValue="#{cRVariable}" itemLabel="#{cRVariable.varName}" converter="#{cRImageTypeConverter}" immediate="true" rendered="true" >
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available Variables</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Associated Variables</f:facet>                
</p:pickList>
```

The action attribute is meant for business logic. You can catch here the source and target list.
The process attribute tell JSF which components to process. In your case, you want the component `picklist` and `commandButton` to be processed. You can also process the whole form with `process="@form"`.

```
<p:commandButton id='varassociate' action="#{reportConfiguratorBean.readMyAssocImTypVariables}" value='Associate' ajax='false' process="@this,pickList" immediate="true" />
```

The readMyAssocImTypVariables function :

```
 public void readMyAssocImTypVariables() {      
    List<CRVariable> sourceVariables = this.dualListVars.getSource();
    List<CRVariable> targetVariables = this.dualListVars.getTarget();       
    for (CRVariable sourceVariable:sourceVariables) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a source variable: " + sourceVariable.getVarName());
    }       
    for (CRVariable targetVariable:targetVariables) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> I am a target variable: " + targetVariable.getVarName());
     }       
  }
```

**Unrelated** : 
Do NOT put business logic into getters/setters ! They are called multiple time by JSF.

Comment: The problem is that when i call the picklist with "<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}" ...> " source and target values are not populated (they should!) ... dualListModel exist as property with getters + setters in the backbean

Comment: nope... reportConfiguratorBean.readMyAssocImTypVariables can not retrieve ALTERED values from picklist ... It retrieves the initial picklist values (before adding initial source values to target)...

Comment: Like Jens suggest the immediate attribute is maybe the problem.

Comment: Add a @PostConstruct to your getAssocImTypVariables function. And call value="#{reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}" in picklist.

Comment: Added but still my picklist is EMPTY if i call it like : alue="#{reportConfiguratorBean.dualListVars}"

Comment: Cleared my eclipse project and now it works fine! Thanks for suggestions guys!

Answer (score 0):

a running picklist example
picklist.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">


<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h3>Basic PickList</h3>
    <p:pickList value="#{pickListBean.cities}" var="city"
        itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" />
<p:commandButton  value="Submit" action="#{pickListBean.displayList}" />    


</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

PickListBean.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel;

@ManagedBean
public class PickListBean {

   private DualListModel<String> cities;

   public PickListBean() {

  //Cities
  List<String> citiesSource = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<String> citiesTarget = new ArrayList<String>();

  citiesSource.add("Istanbul");
  citiesSource.add("Ankara");
  citiesSource.add("Izmir");
  citiesSource.add("Antalya");
  citiesSource.add("Bursa");
//  citiesTarget.add("T1");


  cities = new DualListModel<String>(citiesSource, citiesTarget);
   }

   public DualListModel<String> getCities() {
      return cities;
   }
   public void setCities(DualListModel<String> cities) {
      this.cities = cities;
   }
   public void displayList(){

     System.out.println("values in list are" +cities.getTarget());


   }


}
```

Comment: How does that example is an answer? A running picklist example can be found on [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf) as well. Try to answer the question.